# Application crashing on one computer and not other after deployment

Tags: .net, deployment

My question is why would a .net program operate differently between different computers (both with the same OS)?

Here is the background info:

1. I have built a large .NET 4 application in C#.
2. I have created an installer and installed the application.
3. I have ran the application on a virtual machine under Windows 7 64bit; it works fine.
4. I have created a default unhandled exception dialog which I can force with a menu option that calls throw new Exception("Forced exception for testing.");

Now this dialog works if the unfortuniate does happen etc...

BUT,

When I install this application on another workstation that has Win 7 64bit then the software does not handle the exception in the same way and it crashes at various points that my test version does not?

We are trying a re-install of the .NET framework.

Comment: The answer on you question is very simple, both computers are not the same (updates, culture settings, etc), or your installation is not the same on both computers.

Comment: Implement a handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Thanks for these sugguestions.  The AppDomain.CurrentDomin.UnhandledException is actually already in use but the debug/release issue along with a lack of windows updating seemed to inhibit it.  I guess that the specific machine was getting some issue trying to workout where or which JIT debugger to use...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many reasons why this could be happening and I would check first in the OS event logs to see if they give you any pointers on where to look.

The obvious points to check:
Debug/Release build.

OS patch mismatch (particularly involving .NET)

NET version mismatch.

DLL dependency version mismatches.

Dependent DLLs not correctly registered.

Mismatch in paths for items.

Anti-virus software.

Hardware related differences.

And a big bugbear on Vista/Windows 7 program access rights for the program.

I would start by installing a release version of the program on your development machine.

Comment: I think that this was a Windows Update and debug/release combination. [Ophs pressng enter did not start new line.]  Thanks for your sugguestions they did help :-)